# SQL Server: Find descendants/parent in ID representing a tree

Tags: sql-server, find, parent-child

Given the following table, where a `deptTreeID` of a department represents an ID of an internal node in a tree (so a `deptTreeID` of `001` may have a child `001001`, which may have a child `001001001`), how can I find all of the descendants of a given department?

Likewise, how can I find the direct parent of any given department? (Where the parent of department `001002001` would be `001002`.)

[image]

Comment: is it all increments of 3 characters per level? i.e. department code 1, has tree id 001, and department 3 has id 001001, should we assume this is a child of 001? can we infer that level would be a function of the department tree id length/3?

Comment: Hey! I've rephrased this question to be a little bit more clear—basically your `deptTreeID` is a "path" in a tree of departments, so you can phrase the question in those terms. I've also made your examples a little bit clearer. Good question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like`.  To get all the childrend of `001`:

```
select t.*
from t
where deptTreeId like '001%'
```